# Use the diagonal method to prove that there is a total function from N to N which is not computable

Tags: computability

I'm really not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- The [diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) proved the real numbers to not be countable.
- [Computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number): there is an algorithm that computes it -> there is a Turing machine that computes it. Are those countable?